# maplibregl doesn't show in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maplibre-gl

I add maplibregl in my react js project but https://api.maptiler.com/tiles/v3/2/0/2.pbf?key=my-key
does not load.

```
map = new maplibregl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/basic/style.json?key=my-key', // stylesheet location
            
            center: [-122.4849334359169, 37.829298101706186], // starting position [lng, lat]
            zoom: 13, // starting zoom
            renderWorldCopies: true,
            bounds:[listShips[0].geometry.coordinates,listShips[1].geometry.coordinates],
            fitBoundsOptions: {padding: 300}
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:
you should change the version to

```
   "maplibre-gl": "^1.15.2",
```

on your package.json. Then don't forget to npm i .